# how to keep more space between text in html page?

Tags: html, css

How do I get five more space between text in an HTML page? I am regularly suing `&nbsp;` but it is not enough.

In below example I need more space between LANDMARK and STREET in one line

```
<html>
    <body>
        LANDMARK:<input type="text" name="land_mark">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        SREET:<input type="text" name="street">&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: putting them in div would be better

Comment: I find it interesting that you tagged this question with `css` yet are apparently unaware that that's how you generally do layout in the modern web :-)

Comment: `input { margin-right: 30px; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can seprate the elements close to each other using the `margin` property.

```
input {margin-right: 20px;}
```

---

However, a better way of achieving this would be to change your markup to become a little more semantic, **[a demo here](http://jsbin.com/UlEqOHaV/1/edit)**

HTML :

```
<div class="form_container">
    <form method="POST" name="form_name" class="some_form">
        <label for="land_mark">
            landmark
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="land_mark" id="land_mark" />

        <label for="street">
            street
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="street" id="street" />

    </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.some_form label {
  text-transform : uppercase;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.some_form input {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

**Update**

The reason it is better to use labels to denote the input actions :
[(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3893135/993915)

- clicking the label focuses on the
  text field, which is something a lot 
  of users expect
- it's helpful for the accessibility reasons
- how else is the user going to know which field is which? you could you
  just text or a span or something, but
  why would you?
- It leads to a more semantic markup.

As far as not usng `&nbsp;` goes, it's best to seprate appearance and content, it helps keeping it much cleaner and maintainable. It is much better to just use something like `margin-right : 10px`, than specifying tons of `&nbsp;`

Comment: @mahesh565 The labels create a strong association between the input and the text, which is good for accessibility. Imagine trying to complete a form accurately if all the labels had been randomly jumbled around the page - that can be the experience for users of screen readers without labels. The CSS makes the label text render in upper case, adding a small margin between the label and input, with a larger margin after the input to provide a gap before the next label if you have more than one on a single line. Is there anything else you don't understand?

Comment: nice... i am new to web design sir, bt in my company they r nt teching in depth. i have interest to learn html,css,javascript and php regarding to my company project. i designed one full form bt it is nt in proper margin...

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case(because the two words are in separate tags) a simple

```
margin-left: 20px;
```

would do.

But you should use the [word-spacing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_word-spacing.asp) CSS style to achieve this effect without &nbsp

Answer (score 0):

take some lesson of css. It's very important to use css. margin property is a well solution given to you.But please take some knowledge of css. I bet it will be more helpful for your future plan

Comment: How is this an answer?